# How do I fix a leak in this roof?

Tags: repair, roof

A few days ago we had a good amount of rain that fell over a 36 hour period.  During this time, a leak showed its ugly face. I got up into the attic, found the water stream and traced it back outside to the pictures you see below.  The shingles are about at half of their life.

[image]
[image: some water damage]
[image: up close image]

For reference, I didn't know the exact names, I cheated and used [this](http://www.homeimprovementhelper.com/images/roof/roof_parts_lg.jpg) that way I could speak half-intelligently on it and probably even make sense.

As you can see from the pictures, the water seems to be rolling up under the edge  (where's the drip edge?! even I know that one), getting under the the fascia and on the soffit.  I have a good feeling its following that outside wall there and getting inside.  Bonus, this is a joint between two, decently long slopes (~12'), so it sees a LOT of volume.  As a matter of fact, that last picture, the wood is STILL wet -- it rained 2+ days ago.

Anyway, my idea is to pull the rotten pieces out, nail in some flashing, replace the rotten pieces with fresh ones, maybe put in a drip edge if I can.  Anyone else have any better ideas/pointers and also -- if I had someone do this, what would that run?

Comment: I talked to someone at lowes that told me the local code says the siding should be ~1/4" away from the shingles, and that also because its colder out, I may have to tear up some of the shingles to find the root of the problem ... which I'm about to go do (its 45' out, but there's a lot of sun)

Comment: That sounds pretty good. Make sure water cannot get in from the top of the flashing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is really impossible to correctly answer this question without discovering the root of the problem. Some removal of shingles and or siding may be necessary to inspect the flashing etc. If you find the problem in the valley or around the sidewall, i'd recommend using some ice and water shield under any flashing that may have to be replaced. It can be difficult to find these leaks, so start high and work you way down.  Good luck.

Comment: +1 for start high. A leak that travel a long ways before you notice the damage.

Comment: That was the overall answer I got from two companies that came out -- "we'll have to fix that valley top to bottom, otherwise its just guessing".  Overall estimate on fixing it ~400.